# database app crashes despite incrementing the database's version

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a ListView and I wanted to display my cursor into it, but the app crashes when I execute the code :

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id,  membername,  memberstudylevel, memberbirthday FROM members

This is my code for the database's class:

```
package tn.iac.myapp.application10;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class
    MyBDHelter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "base_de_membre.db";
public static final String TABLE_MEMBERS = "members";
public static final String COLUMN_MEMBERID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_MEMBERNAME = "membername";
public static final String COLUMN_MEMBERSTUDYLEVEL = "memberstudylevel";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "memberemail";
public static final String COLUMN_MEMBERBIRTHDAY = "memberbirthday";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

public MyBDHelter(Context context, String  name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBERS + "("
            +COLUMN_MEMBERID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COLUMN_MEMBERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_MEMBERSTUDYLEVEL + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_MEMBERBIRTHDAY + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBERS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor getallusers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] strings = {"_id"," membername", " memberstudylevel", "memberbirthday"};
    Cursor c=db.query(
            true,
            TABLE_MEMBERS,
            strings,
            "",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if(c!=null){
    c.moveToFirst();}
    db.close();
    return c;
}

public void addmember(Membre membre) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_MEMBERNAME, membre.get_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_MEMBERBIRTHDAY, membre.get_birth());
    values.put(COLUMN_MEMBERSTUDYLEVEL, membre.get_study_level());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, membre.get_password());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, membre.get_Email());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_MEMBERS, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public boolean exist(String name, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_MEMBERNAME + "=\"" + name + "\" AND " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=\"" + password + "\";";
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.getCount() >= 1)
        return true;
    return false;

}

public void changepassword(String password, String oldpassword, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_MEMBERS + " SET " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=\"" + password + "\" WHERE " + COLUMN_MEMBERNAME + "=\"" + name + "\"AND "
            + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=\"" +
            oldpassword + "\";";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.close();
}

public Membre databasetostring(String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBERS, new String[]{COLUMN_MEMBERNAME,
                    COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_MEMBERSTUDYLEVEL, COLUMN_MEMBERBIRTHDAY, COLUMN_PASSWORD}, COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=?",
            new String[]{password.toString()}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Membre membre = new Membre(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));

    return membre;
}
}
```

And this is my code to show the ListView:

```
package tn.iac.myapp.application10;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class List_user extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
MyBDHelter bdHelter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_user);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    bdHelter = new MyBDHelter(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 4);
    Cursor cursor = bdHelter.getallusers();
    int[] toviews = {R.id.user_id_item, R.id.name_item_user, R.id.studylevell_user_item, R.id.birthday_userèitem};
    String[] strings = {"_id", " membername", "memberstudylevel", "memberbirthday"};
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_item, cursor,
            strings, toviews);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

}}
```

P.S.: I declared the primary key "_id", and I incremented the database's version, 
but the problem still exists

Error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id,  membername,  memberstudylevel, memberbirthday FROM members
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
  at tn.iac.myapp.application10.MyBDHelter.getallusers(MyBDHelter.java:51)
  at tn.iac.myapp.application10.List_user.onCreate(List_user.java:19)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Please copy the logcat of the crash, highlighting to which line of code corresponds to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space here:

```
+COLUMN_MEMBERID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
```

has to be

```
+COLUMN_MEMBERID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
```

THEN increment the DATABASE_VERSION constant.
(Or uninstall and then reinstall your app)

Comment: Great. Accept my answer, then. So your post will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score -1):

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id,  membername,  memberstudylevel, memberbirthday FROM members
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                                                                          at tn.iac.myapp.application10.MyBDHelter.getallusers(MyBDHelter.java:51)
                                                                          at tn.iac.myapp.application10.List_user.onCreate(List_user.java:19)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```